# Web scrape synonyms

Tags: r, web-scraping, purrr, rvest

I am trying to scrape synonyms from the National Cancer Institute Thesaurus data base, however I am having some trouble finding the right html to point to for this. Below is my code and the data frame I am using. When I run my script to pull the synonyms I get an `Error in open.connection(x, "rb") : HTTP error 404.` I cant seem to figure out what the right html link should be and how to find it.

[image]

```
library(xml2)
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyverse)

synonyms<-read_csv("terms.csv")
##list of acronyms 
words <- c(synonyms$Keyword)

##Designate html like and the values to search 
htmls <- paste0("https://ncit.nci.nih.gov/ncitbrowser/pages/concept_details.jsf/", words)

Data<-data.frame(Pages=c(htmls))


results<-sapply(Data$Pages, function(url){
  try(
    url %>%
      as.character() %>% 
      read_html() %>% 
      html_nodes('p') %>% 
      html_text()
  )
})
```

Comment: Actually, ignore that, I think I misunderstood your problem. I'm going to attempt a proper answer.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect there's a problem with this line of code:

```
##Designate html like and the values to search 
htmls <- paste0("https://ncit.nci.nih.gov/ncitbrowser/pages/concept_details.jsf/", words)
```

Because [paste0() just concatenates text together](https://www.r-bloggers.com/difference-between-paste-and-paste0/), this will give you you URLs like

```
https://ncit.nci.nih.gov/ncitbrowser/pages/concept_details.jsf/Ketamine
https://ncit.nci.nih.gov/ncitbrowser/pages/concept_details.jsf/Azacitidine
https://ncit.nci.nih.gov/ncitbrowser/pages/concept_details.jsf/Axicabtagene+Ciloleucel
```

While I do not have particular experience with `rvest`, the 404 error you see is almost certainly tied to the inability of web browsers to load those URLs. I recommend logging or printing out `htmls` so you can confirm that they indeed work properly in a web browser.

I will point out that in this particular case the website offers [a downloadable database](https://evs.nci.nih.gov/ftp1/NCI_Thesaurus/ReadMe.txt); you might find it easier to download and query that offline than to do this web scraping.